# How to remove table tag in form of string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

input is like:

```
text="""Hi Team from the following Server :

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:203pt">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:15.0pt; width:203pt">ratsuite.sby.ibm.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Please archive the following Project Areas :</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:1436pt">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:15.0pt; width:505pt">UNIT TEST - IBM OPAL 3.3 RC3</td>
            <td style="width:328pt">https://ratsuite.sby.ibm.com:9460/ccm</td>
            <td style="width:603pt">https://ratsuite.sby.ibm.com:9460/ccm/process/project-areas/_ckR-QJiUEeOXmZKjKhPE4Q</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>"""
```

In output i want these 2 lines only, want to remove table tag with data in python:

Hi Team from the following Server :

Please archive the following Project Areas :

Comment: Take a look at the Beautiful Soup library for parsing HTML: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Please share me any solution without using any external lib. is it possible to do with regular expression.

Comment: It is possible to do using regex. You can use a site like https://regexr.com to build your pattern and python regex library to apply it https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. While we're all happy to help solving a problem, it's your duty to _first_ try and solve it by yourself - SO is not a free programming service. Please edit your post to explain what you've tried and why/how it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BeautifulSoup` to parse HTML

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text="""<p>Hi Team from the following Server :</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:203pt">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:15.0pt; width:203pt">ratsuite.sby.ibm.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Please archive the following Project Areas :</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:1436pt">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:15.0pt; width:505pt">UNIT TEST - IBM OPAL 3.3 RC3</td>
            <td style="width:328pt">https://ratsuite.sby.ibm.com:9460/ccm</td>
            <td style="width:603pt">https://ratsuite.sby.ibm.com:9460/ccm/process/project-areas/_ckR-QJiUEeOXmZKjKhPE4Q</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
for p in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(p.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Hi Team from the following Server :

Please archive the following Project Areas :
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
If input is not in <p> tag and i wan't these details also in output. then how i will do?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use external library, you can use `re` module to remove tables:

```
output = re.sub('<table.+?</table>','',text,flags=re.DOTALL)
```

printing output give:

```
Hi Team from the following Server :



<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Please archive the following Project Areas :</p>
```

(and 2 empty lines which are not visible there).

Regarding pattern notice that `+` is followed by `?` meaning use non-greedy matching - otherwise it would purge anything between begin of first table and end of last table. `re.DOTALL` is required, because our substrings contain newlines (`\n`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLParser` as demonstrated below:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

s = \
"""
<html>
<p>Hi Team from the following Server :</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:203pt">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:15.0pt; width:203pt">ratsuite.sby.ibm.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Please archive the following Project Areas :</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:1436pt">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:15.0pt; width:505pt">UNIT TEST - IBM OPAL 3.3 RC3</td>
            <td style="width:328pt">https://ratsuite.sby.ibm.com:9460/ccm</td>
            <td style="width:603pt">https://ratsuite.sby.ibm.com:9460/ccm/process/project-areas/_ckR-QJiUEeOXmZKjKhPE4Q</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
"""

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self._last_tag = ''

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        #print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
        self._last_tag = tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        #print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
        self._last_tag = ''

    def handle_data(self, data):
        #print "Encountered some data  :", data
        if self._last_tag == 'p':
            print("<%s> tag data: %s" % (self._last_tag, data))

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(s)
```

Output:

```
<p> tag data: Hi Team from the following Server :
<p> tag data: Please archive the following Project Areas :
```